# Listar somente arquivos sem pastas em dirétorio em Python

Tags: python

Preciso listar arquivos em um diretório, mas preciso que liste somente os arquivos, sem mostrar alguma pasta se tiver nesse diretório.

Utilizei:

```
import os
print os.listdir('/')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com as respostas [dessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory) e [dessa outra pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176166/list-only-files-in-a-directory), você pode utilizar comandos como:

---

**Cod1:**

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

mypath = '/home/'

onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
print(onlyfiles)
```

Retorna somente os arquivos na pasta `mypath`.

---

**Cod2:**

```
import glob
print glob.glob("/home/user/*.txt")
```

Você pode alterar `*.txt` para `*.*` para pegar arquivos com qualquer tipo de extensão.
No entanto, se sua pasta tiver uma subpasta com o nome `pasta.pasta1`, o comando `*.*` retornará essa subpasta também...

---

**Cod3:**

```
import os
filenames = next(os.walk(path))[2]
```

Retorna somente o terceiro parametro do método [walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk), que no caso, são os `filenames`

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou com walk

Comment: @Will Se a resposta lhe foi útil você pode marcá-la como correta usando o **V** do lado esquerdo da mesma.

Comment: Feito brother. Obrigado