# Retorno de consulta mysql numa lista python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Boa Tarde! como faço para pegar os dados que retornam da consulta sql e jogar numa lista sabendo que preciso do retorno da consulta = ao retorno da pasta de arquivos + os arquivos maiores que a consulta.??
Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

```
#Busca no banco de dados o ultimo Id inserido
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('Select posicao, ArquivoLog from logbin where Id = (select max(Id) from logbin)')
recordset = cursor.fetchall()
execucao_anterior = recordset[0]
#Retorno da consulta mysql 
#bin-log.000028

#le os arquivos da pasta logs
os.chdir("C:\\Backups\\Logs\\")
lista = glob.glob("*.0*")
tm_lista = (len(lista))
posicao_na_lista = ((lista.index(arquivo_anterior)))   
print(posicao_na_lista)

#retorno
#bin-log.000028
#bin-log.000029
#bin-log.000030
#bin-log.000031
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá!
Fiz uma consulta usando o Sqlite3 do própio Python e salvando o retorno da consulta em um arquivo "txt".
Espero que te ajude.

```
import sqlite3
conteudo = []

conection = sqlite3.connect('banco.db')
c = conection.cursor()
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS REMESSA (DATA VARCHAR(50), HORA VARCHAR(50), DESCRICAO VARCHAR(50))')
c.execute('INSERT INTO REMESSA (DATA,HORA,DESCRICAO) VALUES ("10","20","30")')
conection.commit()

teste = c.execute('SELECT * FROM REMESSA')

for row in teste:
    conteudo.append(row)
arquivo = open('C:/Teste/Arquivo_Teste_2.txt','w')
arquivo.writelines(str(conteudo))
arquivo.close()
```

Abs!

Comment: Lucas valeu pela ajuda, mas estou precisando mesmo e fazer uma comparação dos dados tenho um banco que guarda as informações de log. na minha consulta acima busco a última inserção no meu bd, agora preciso comparar com os arquivos que busco na pasta com os da consulta e salvar numa variável.
 Retorno da consulta do bd foi bin-log.000035 E tenho na pasta dos seguintes arquivos 'bin-log.000034', 'bin-log.000035', 'bin-log.000036', 'bin-log.000037', 'bin-log.000038'
Preciso pegar os arquivos ‘bin-log.000035', 'bin-log.000036', 'bin-log.000037', 'bin-log.000038'
 E jogar numa variável.

Comment: Olha só, de repente pode usar o conteúdo deste link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/200249/listar-somente-arquivos-sem-pastas-em-dir%C3%A9torio-em-python
É demonstrado como listar os arquivos de um determinado diretório, aí basta comparar as duas listas em um for e os que forem diferentes salva em uma variável.